# Exercise about Schwarz Lemma

Tags: complex-analysis

This is an exericse about the Schwarz Lemma:

> Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}$  be a simply connected domain and
> $z_0 \in \Omega \neq \mathbb{C}$. Furthermore, let $f, g: \Omega \to \Omega$ biholomorphic such that
>
> \begin{align} f(z_0) = g(z_0), \qquad f'(z_0) = g'(z_0). \end{align}
>
> Proof that $f = g$.

The hint states to use Schwarz's Lemma as well as Riemann's mapping theorem. In fact later only allows me to use Schwarz's Lemma (in this case). Could someone give me a proper (second) hint how to use Schwarz's Lemma to show that $f = g$? Should I consider using $h:= f-g$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\Omega\subsetneq\Bbb C$ is simply connected, then by the Riemann mapping theorem we know that it exists $h:\Omega\to\Delta$ biholomorphic such that $h(z_0)=0,\; h'(z_0)\neq0$, where $\Delta$ is the open unit disk.

Consider then
$$
F:=h\circ g^{-1}\circ f\circ h^{-1}\colon\Delta\to\Delta
$$
which is a biholomorphism such that $F(0)=0$ and $|F(z)|<1$ on the whole $\Delta$; thus by Schwartz Lemma we get
\begin{align*}
&|F(z)|\le|z|\;\;\forall z\in\Delta.
\end{align*}
Schwartz applies to $F^{-1}$ as well letting us to achieve $|F^{-1}(w)|\le|w|\;\;\forall w \in\Delta$.

Since every $w\in\Delta$ can be written as $F(z)$ for a unique $z\in\Delta$, we get

$$
|z|\le|F(z)|\;\;\; \forall w\in\Delta
$$
and thus
$$
|F(z)|=|z|\;\;\forall z\in\Delta.
$$
So Schwarz implies $F(z)=az$ for some $a\in\Bbb C,\;|a|=1$.

Taking the derivative of this last one at $0$ one and exploiting your hypotesis on $f$ and $g$, you get that $a=1$ and thus $f=g$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Any bi-holomorphic map from the unit disk $U$ onto itself is of the form $z \to e^{i\theta} \frac {z-a}{1-\overline a z}$ where $|a|<1$ and $\theta \in \mathbb R$
. If two such maps have the same value and the same derivative at some point then the values of $\theta$ and $a$ coincide  and the functions are therefore equal. Now apply RMP to prove the same for any simply connected region $\Omega$ other than $\mathbb C$.